# Error while instalation of new bundles in Symfony2 Composer.phar

Tags: symfony

I have a problem when i install a new bundle, when i use this command:

```sh
php composer.phar require mesd/jasper-report-bundle "~1.0"
```

It displays the following error:

```sh
C:\wamp\www\ADMSymfony>php composer.phar require mesd/jasper-report-bundle "~1.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle == 1.3.5.0 could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

here is my composer.json :

```javascript
{
    "require": {
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "widop/google-analytics-bundle": "*",
        "whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding: `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in your `composer.json`?

Comment: Yes, i tried it but it still the same problem

Comment: Somehow Composer is trying to install the actually non existing version 1.3.5.0. Can you try deleting your composer.lock file and running `composer install` before you require that bundle?

Comment: I don't have Composer.lock, when i run the command  composer.phar update all the bundles removed and it install new others

Comment: I tried on symfony 2.3 installation with all your bundles and it was installed successfully. Probably problem can be in symfony version or composer settings.

Comment: I have the version 2.6 of symfony, it still the same problem.